# Cannot submit a HIT I created in MTurk without receiving submission error every time

Tags: html, mechanicalturk

I'm trying to create a simple HIT in Amazon MTurk Sandbox using a xml/html design layout and python to create the actual HIT (following two tutorials from MTurk itself). However, whenever I go to the HITs as a Worker and try to submit them I get this response: "There was a problem submitting your results for this HIT." I've gone through multiple forums and changed many things accordingly but keep getting the same result.

Any advice would be great! It's a simple task that I'm doing just to get a hang of using MTurk and everything else seems to be working and showing up fine.

This is my code for the submit:

```
<p><input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="commit" value="Complete HIT"/></p></form>
<script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();,</script>
```

And this is my earlier code to begin the form:

```
<form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'><input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw two things which could be the problem:

1. You have a `,` after `turkSetAssignmentID()` which is a JavaScript syntax error. This prevents the code from running and prevents the function from setting the correct endpoint for the form, which causes the error.
2. You might not be doing a `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>` in the `<head>` tag. This tells the browser to fetch a helper script, which is where the `turkSetAssignmentID()` function is defined.

If you fix these problem, it should work. Here's a complete example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
  <HTMLContent><![CDATA[

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://s3.amazonaws.com/mturk-public/externalHIT_v1.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>

  <form name='mturk_form' method='post' id='mturk_form' action='https://www.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'><input type='hidden' value='' name='assignmentId' id='assignmentId'/>
  <p><input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="commit" value="Complete HIT"/></p></form>
  <script language='Javascript'>turkSetAssignmentID();</script>
  </body>
</html>


  ]]>
  </HTMLContent>
  <FrameHeight>0</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
```

An **easier way to do this with less code** would be to use [Crowd HTML Elements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle.html#ApiReference_HTMLQuestionArticle-crowd). You don't have to do as many `<script>` tags and provides powerful widgets like bounding boxes and form validation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?>
<HTMLQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2011-11-11/HTMLQuestion.xsd">
  <HTMLContent><![CDATA[

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>
  <crowd-form>
    <!-- form contents goes here -->
  </crowd-form>
</html>

  ]]>
  </HTMLContent>
  <FrameHeight>0</FrameHeight>
</HTMLQuestion>
```